# WGET command line for download videos

Tags: command-line, download, wget

I'm trying to figure out WGET for downloading some videos at http://windowsclient.net/learn/videos_wpf.aspx.

This page is an index page, and contains links to a page for each video; each page then has a direct link to a video. Something like;

```
http://windowsclient.net/learn/videos_wpf.aspx
  -> http://windowsclient.net/learn/video.aspx?v=300881
    -> http://download.microsoft.com/[...]/HDI-WPF-ipod-AccelerometerJoystick(2).mp4
```

What I'd like to do is tell WGET to spider the site by following either `video.aspx?*` or `.mp4` links, recurively, for two levels. I can figure out

```
WGET -r -l2 http://windowsclient.net/learn/videos_wpf.aspx
```

and then I get stuck. Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Thanks to @mloskot, I got the answer;

```
WGET -r -l2 -A.mp4,video*.aspx* 
  --domains=windowsclient.net,download.microsoft.com 
  --span-hosts 
  http://windowsclient.net/learn/videos_wpf.aspx
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Learn about option `-A` in the [2.11](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Recursive-Accept_002fReject-Options) and 4.2 chapter of wget manual and use this option to *specify comma-separated lists of file name suffixes or patterns to accept*. In other words, use `-A` to specify that you want to download only files with `mp4` extension:

```
WGET -r -l2 -A.mp4 http://windowsclient.net/learn/videos_wpf.aspx
```

Comment: Perfect! You helped me get the right command line, which I'm including back in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I found that added the -np flag (no parents) helped, preventing it from downloading a large number of other pages rather than just the videos on the page I was trying to process.